# NullPointer Exception in onDestroy

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have this function in my `onDestroy` function and it's causing a crash:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Server.setPresence(false, CONSTANTS.USER.userId);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

---

**Server.Java**

```
private static final String TAG = "Cove Server";
private static final String PATH = "http://10.0.0.2:8001/data_connection";
private static HttpResponse response = null;
private static StringEntity se = null;
private static final int TIMEOUT = 30000;
private static HttpParams hParams = new BasicHttpParams();
private static HttpClient client;
private static HttpPost post = null;
public static String actionKey = null;

private static JSONObject sendRequest(JSONObject req) {
    try {
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(hParams, TIMEOUT);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient(hParams);
        actionKey = req.getString("actionKey");
        se = new StringEntity(req.toString());
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_ENCODING,
                "application/json"));
        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "application/json"));
        post = new HttpPost(PATH);
        post.setEntity(se);

        Log.d(TAG, "http request is being sent");
        response = client.execute(post);
        Log.d(TAG, "http request was sent");

        if (response != null
                && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String a = convertFromInputStream(in); // CALLS A FUNCTION THAT PARSES THE RESPONSE TO String
            in.close();
            return new JSONObject(a);
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "encoding request to String entity faild!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "executing the http POST didn't work");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "executing the http POST didn't work");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "no ActionKey");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static JSONObject setPresence(boolean isActive, String userId) {
    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    try {
        request.put("actionKey", (isActive) ? "UserPresenceActive"
                : "UserPresenceInactive");
        request.put("userId", userId);
        return sendRequest(request);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**logcat**

```
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.yishai/com.thepoosh.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3124)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3142)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:127)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1192)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at com.thepoosh.MyActivity.onDestroy(MyActivity.java:340)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:4629)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1082)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3111)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    ... 11 more
```

I'm suspecting that since the server is not sending back a response and the `Server.setPresence()` doesn't return and therefore the app goes into ANR.

Is that correct? What should I do to fix this? Is there a different reason for the crash?

Comment: what is  CONSTANTS.USER there ? if CONSTANTS i file then provide the code......

Comment: `CONSTANTS.USER` is a static variable that holds the current user

Comment: yup so that may be null see my answer and test that is that not null......

Comment: why Sameer deleted the answer ?

Comment: yup but how ? BTW have you put the check for CONSTANTS.USER ?

Comment: Between you should call **super.onDestroy();** before anything else in **onDestroy()**.

Comment: @Creator from I understand this is the absolute LAST thing to do in this function

Comment: Actually the call to the overriden superclass method in the overriding subclass method must be the first one to get called. That's why we need to call super.onCreate() first in onCreate(). And super.onDestroy() won't destroy your app immediately, all your code in onDestroy() will run first.

Comment: are you sure?! it seems like `onCreate` should be called first (for all the preparations) and `onDestroy` last because everything has stopped for me and I'm ready for the final touches of destroying my activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at com.thepoosh.MyActivity.onDestroy(MyActivity.java:340)
06-28 12:59:11.970: E/AndroidRuntime(19806):    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:4629)
```

looks on `onDestroy is last function is stacktrace` so call not went to Server.setPresence yet .. so it looks `USER` in `CONSTANTS.USER.userId`  may be only null  at that line. so put a check to test out that.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(null==CONSTANTS.USER){
    Server.setPresence(false, CONSTANTS.USER.userId);
    }else{
         Toast.makeText(this,"is null",Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
      }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: thanks a bunch. it worked and now all I have is the annoying `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` for calling an HTTP POST on the UI thread.

Comment: so I think you know that how to handle that ..... :) just keep in mind it may possible until your result will come in other thread from server your activity will be destroyed

Comment: please take a look at my new question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11243056/1056359