# implications of AsyncTask.execute in onDestroy

Tags: android, ondestroy

I have this code running in my `onDestroy` function:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (!(null == theUser.glideId)) {
        JSONObject req = new JSONObject();
        try {
            req.put("actionKey", "UserPresenceInactive");
            req.put("userId", theUser.userId);
            new ServerRequest().execute(req); //Run an AsyncTask
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

In the `AsyncTask` I send a request to a server (that comes back with just a 200 response).

My question is, what are the implications (if any) for doing this?

Does the Activity get destroyed? Does the app stay awake and might go into ANR if the server doesn't respond? any thoughts?

**edit**

I tried doing this instead but got a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

```
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JSONObject req = new JSONObject();
            try {
                req.put("actionKey", "UserPresenceInactive");
                req.put("userId", theUser.userId);
                new ServerRequest().execute(req); //Run an AsyncTask
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.run();
```

**UPDATE #2**

using a `Thread` instead of a `Runnable` did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the `Activity` gets destroyed but the `AsyncTask` is doing its job(working in background). There won't be any `ANR` because you are not doing any background stuff on the UI. If you are updating any view on your UI after `AsyncTask` is completed then there would a `NULLPOINTER Exception` AFAIK. But, this would not be a good idea to run AsyncTask in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: what would you suggest me doing?

Comment: What is making you run AsyncTask when Activity is getting destroyed?

Comment: I need to notify a server that I am offline once the app closes.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be run your AsyncTask in method such as onPause() or onSaveInstanceState() and not in onDestroy()

Looking at developer android reference:

> OnPause():
>   This callback is mostly used for saving any persistent state the activity is editing, to present a "edit in place" model to the user and making sure nothing is lost if there are not enough resources to start the new activity without first killing this one. This is also a good place to do things like stop animations and other things that consume a noticeable amount of CPU in order to make the switch to the next activity as fast as possible, or to close resources that are exclusive access such as the camera.
>
> In situations where the system needs more memory it may kill paused processes to reclaim resources. Because of this, you should be sure that all of your state is saved by the time you return from this function. In general onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is used to save per-instance state in the activity and this method is used to store global persistent data (in content providers, files, etc.)

Comment: but, I need to notify the server only when the user exits the app. consider the scenario of the user getting a call during the use of the app, the `onPause` function will be called and my server will decide incorrectly that the user is no longer an active user...

Comment: for only this issue, can use isFinishing () this is often used in onPause() to determine whether the activity is simply pausing or completely finishing. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()